# Fastest way to write vector <pair <double,double> to file

Tags: c++, file, vector, std-pair

I'm trying to write a lot of x/y double points to a file.

I came up with the following function to be the fastest solution, yet.

Are there any other ways speed up the process?

Writing to the stringstream first and then opening the file gave a nice speed boost.

```
bool printPoints(const vector <pair <double,double> > &points, const string &file)
{
    if(points.empty())
        return false;

    vector <pair <double,double> > const_iterator i;

    if(file != "")
    {
        stringstream ss;
        for(i=points.begin(); i != points.end();++i )
        {
           ss << i->first << " " << i->second << "\n";
        }

        ofstream out(file.c_str());
        if(out.fail())
        {
            out.close();
            return false;
        }
        out << ss.str();
        out.close();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Try streaming stringstream's buffer directly, see if it makes a difference: `out << ss.rdbuf();`.

Comment: Also, try using C I/O (`FILE*`). But I don't think any significant improvements are possible.

Comment: I tried `rdbuf()` instead of `.str()` but didn't notice any difference

Comment: How many coordinates do you actually have?

Comment: I have 2-10 thousand but benchmarked with 100k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this. Writing to a `stringstream` buys you next to nothing. Using `FILE *` instead of `fstream` does give a reasonable improvement.

Here's my test-code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

bool printPoints(const vector <pair <double,double> > &points, const string &file)
{
    if(points.empty())
        return false;

    vector <pair <double,double> >::const_iterator i;

    if(file != "")
    {
        stringstream ss;
        for(i=points.begin(); i != points.end();++i )
        {
           ss << i->first << " " << i->second << "\n";
        }

        ofstream out(file.c_str());
        if(out.fail())
        {
            out.close();
            return false;
        }
        out << ss.str();
        out.close();
    }
    return true;
}

bool printPoints2(const vector <pair <double,double> > &points, const string &file)
{
    if(points.empty())
        return false;

    vector <pair <double,double> >:: const_iterator i;

    if(file != "")
    {
        ofstream out(file.c_str());
        if(out.fail())
        {
            out.close();
            return false;
        }
        for(i=points.begin(); i != points.end();++i )
        {
           out << i->first << " " << i->second << "\n";
        }

        out.close();
    }
    return true;
}


bool printPoints3(const vector <pair <double,double> > &points, const string &file)
{
    if(points.empty())
        return false;

    vector <pair <double,double> >:: const_iterator i;

    if(file != "")
    {
    FILE *out = fopen(file.c_str(), "w");
        if(!out)
        {
            return false;
        }
        for(i=points.begin(); i != points.end();++i )
        {
        fprintf(out, "%f %f", i->first, i->second);
        }

        fclose(out);
    }
    return true;
}

static __inline__ unsigned long long rdtsc(void)
{
    unsigned hi, lo;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi));
    return ( (unsigned long long)lo)|( ((unsigned long long)hi)<<32 );
}

int main()
{
    vector <pair <double,double> >  v;
    unsigned long long t1, t2;

    for(int i = 1; i <= 10000000; i++)
    {
    v.push_back(make_pair<double, double>((double)i, 1.0/i)); 
    }
    t1 = rdtsc();
    printPoints(v, "points.txt");
    t2 = rdtsc();
    cout << "time = " << t2 - t1 << endl;
    t1 = rdtsc();
    printPoints2(v, "points2.txt");
    t2 = rdtsc();
    cout << "time = " << t2 - t1 << endl;
    t1 = rdtsc();
    printPoints3(v, "points3.txt");
    t2 = rdtsc();
    cout << "time = " << t2 - t1 << endl;
}
```

---

```
Results:
time = 55363637480
time = 54413392112
time = 33069402767
```

Obviously, the results may vary depending on the processor type, memory type, hard disk system (or network drive storage), etc, etc. But I've tested this in the past, and found similar results.

Comment: Solution 3 worked best for me. In my test the native solution took about 46secs, mine 22 and your 3rd about 19secs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Serializing of the coordinates can be parallelized by dividing the input across several threads and then joining the return values from them. Then writing the returned value to the file. This way we can speed up the process.

Answer (score 1):

You can gain some speed boost by writing all coord at once in binary format

```
ofstream out(file.c_str(),std::ios_base::binary);
out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(points.begin()),sizeof(double)*2*points.size());
```

It may not work if points are not stored contigously in memory for pair (for vector they are), then you may copy it to a single vector of double first (x,y,x,y...) in vector of double, write to disk next.

Comment: That clearly assumes that the format where this is used later is "flexible".

Comment: I don't want them to be binary. Any way to use your solution and still have them readable?

Comment: Closest would be to use atoi to convert doubles to char, append them to string, then binary write string to file - that would use same approach avoiding streams, however, I'm not sure how much gain would you get

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider memory-mapped-file? Just copy necessary data (in serialized representation, of course) to a memory area returned by in-mem file mapping, then close the mapping. From my past experience, this is quite fast way to transfer large amounts of data from STL structures to file.

Comment: What about portability? Memory aligment, endianess, etc? Serialization in C++ is not as easy as in Java.

Comment: Can you tell me more about it? Haven't used memory mapping yet.

Comment: MMF allows you to allocate a memory chunk with special OS marker. If you associate a file with that memory, OS will sync them together, if no file assocated the memory block will be associated with system swap http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef pair<double, double> PDD;

namespace std {

  inline
  ostream&
  operator<<(ostream& os, const PDD& p)
  {
    return os << p.first << ' ' << p.second;
  }

}

bool
PrintPoints(const vector<PDD>& points, const string& file)
{
  if (points.empty() || file.empty())
    return false;

  ofstream fout(file.c_str());
  if (!fout)
    return false;

  copy(points.begin(), points.end(), ostream_iterator<PDD>(fout, "\n"));

  return true;
}
```

Close will be called by `ofstream` dtor.

Comment: Might look nice, but doesn't give me a speed boost.

Comment: I agree, but I thought this was already clear: the only consistent speed boost you can have is by implementing it via C I/O as suggested by Mats. Furthermore, this difference might be observable only on fast hardware (like SSD) and might otherwise be hidden by much larger effect of a hardware bandwidth.